# When do you need to pass arguments to python super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

A use case of the `super()` builtin in python is to call an overridden method. Here is a simple example of using `super()` to call `Parent` class's `echo` function:

```py
class Parent():
    def echo(self):
        print("in Parent")

class Child(Parent):
    def echo(self):
        super().echo()
        print("in Child")
```

I've seen code that passes 2 parameters to `super()`. In that case, the signature looks somehing like `super(subClass, instance)` where `subClass` is the sub class calling `super()` from, and `instance` is the instance the call being made from, ie `self`. So in the above example, the `super()` line would become:

```py
super(Child, self).echo()
```

Looking at [python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), these 2 use cases are the same when calling from inside of a class.

Is calling `super()` with 2 parameters completely deprecated as of python3? If this is only deprecated for calling overridden functions, can you show an example why they're needed for other cases?

I'm also interested to know why python needed those 2 arguments? Are they injected/evaluated when making `super()` calls in python3, or they're just not needed in that case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't pass the arguments, Python 3 makes an effort to provide them for you. It's a little kludgy, but it *usually* works. Essentially, it just assumes the first parameter to your method is `self` (the second argument to `super`), and when the class definition completes, it provides a virtual closure scope for any function that refers to `super` or `__class__` that defines `__class__` as the class you just defined, so no-arg `super()` can check the stack frame to find `__class__` as the first argument.

This usually works, but there are cases where it doesn't:

- In `staticmethod`s (since the first argument isn't actually the class), though `staticmethod`s aren't really supposed to participate in the inheritance hierarchy the same way, so that's not exactly unexpected.
- In functions that take `*args` as the first argument (which was the only safe way to implement any method that accepted arbitrary keyword arguments like `dict` subclasses prior to 3.8, when they introduced positional-only arguments).
- If the `super` call is in a nested scope, which can be implicit, e.g. a generator expression, or comprehension of any kind (`list`, `set`, `dict`), since the nested scope isn't directly attached to the class, so it doesn't get the `__class__` defining magic that methods attached to the class itself get.

There are also rare cases where you might want to explicitly bypass a particular class for resolving the parent method, in which case you'd need to explicitly pass a different class from later in the MRO than the one it would pull by default. This is deep and terrible magic, so I don't recommend it, but I think I've had cause to do it once.

**All of those are relatively rare cases, so most of the time, for code purely targeting Python 3, you're fine using no-arg `super`, and only falling back to explicitly passing arguments when you *can't* use it for whatever reason.** No-arg `super` is cleaner, faster, and during live development can be more correct (if you replace `MyClass`, instances of the old version of the class will have the old version cached and no-arg `super` will continue to work, where looking it up manually in your globals would find the new version of the class and explode), so use it whenever you can.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `super()` with zero arguments is already the shortcut for `super(__class__, self)`. See [PEP3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) for complete explanation.

This is not the case for Python 2, so I guess that most code examples you found were actually written for Python 2 (or Python2+3 compatible)